# How to add floating button on tableView controller

Tags: swift, uitableview, button

I have a tableView controller.
I want to add a floating button like the button in the YouTube app.
When I drag the button, it's inside the tableView, not floating.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Answer (score 0):

for that case you can use UITableView inside of UIViewController, instead of UITableViewController.
As for UITableViewController when you do something

```
[self.view addSubView:customButton];
//or
[self.tableView addSubView:customButton];
```

then it considers you are adding a subView to your tableView as for tableViewController main view is your tableView.

simply have a UIViewController and add UITableView in it as a subView and also add customButton to your main View as subView.

```
[self.view addSubView:myTableView];
[self.view addSubView:customButton];
```

or you can always create it in IB. :)